# ReactJs - Access Wrapped State from HOC Wrapper

Tags: reactjs

Im trying to use HOC pattern instead of Object Oriented to avoid redundant code.

The situation is simple as explained below:

[image]

In HomePage I have something like this:

```
const WrappedComponent = Wrapper(Wrapped);
<WrappedComponent { ...this.props } />
```

In the Wrapper "component", I want to expose a method called `foo_method` that is an Ajax Call to a WebServer. The result must be written in the state of Wrapped Component.

Now, WrappedComponent can call `foo_method` but when inside Wrapper, I have no scope of Wrapped state and `this.props` contains the props of HomePage, not wrapper so I cant create a callback function in Wrapper to be called.

Am I forgetting something in the implementation of HOC?

Comment: Wrapper can't set state of wrapped component, but it can pass result via props. It can also pass the whole method via props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your HOC should look something like this, every WrappedComponent will get result (null while loading and API response after) in the props also wrapped component can call exposed fetch function manually via props.fetchFunction().

```
function Wrapper(WrappedComponent) {
    const fetchData = () => {
         return fetch('something');
    };

    return class extend React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
             super(props);
             this.state = {
                 result: null,
             };
        }
        componentDidMount() {
             fetchData().then((result) => {
                  this.setState({result});
             });
        }
        render() {
            return (
               <WrappedComponent
                   result={this.state.result}
                   fetchFunction={fetchData}
                   {...this.props}
               />
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You. Your code works perfectly. I was hoping to avoid to use `componentWillReceiveProps` in the Wrapped component but I can live with it.